# Converting text into a link with JavaScript returns an error

Tags: javascript, web

```
 function assert() {
     document.write.apply(document, arguments);   
    }

var testLink = "google.com";

    function makeIntoLink(link) {
        if (link.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(.com)/)) {
            link.replace(link, "<a href=\"http://www." + link+ "\">" + link + "<\/a>");
        }
        return link;
    }



    assert(makeIntoLink(testLink));
```

It writes it down but not in link form. Just "google.com" without the link. What could've gone wrong?

Comment: it should be.. `^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(.com)/)`... because domains can contain hyphens, but that is not problem in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function like `link.replace` doesn't actually replace stuff inside the string, it actually returns a NEW string with the replacements made. For example:

```
function replaceText() {
    var searchText = ".com";
    var link = "google.com";

    var newLink = link.replace(searchText, ".co.uk");

    alert(link); // Output = "google.com"
    alert(newLink); // Output = "google.co.uk"

}
```

In your situation though, you don't need to use `string.replace(...)` at all, instead you can just do this:

```
function makeIntoLink(link) {
    if (link.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(.com)/)) {
        //link.replace(link, "<a href=\"http://www." + link+ "\">" + link + "<\/a>"); <-- OLD
        link = "<a href=\"http://www." + link+ "\">" + link + "<\/a>"; // <-- NEW
    }
    return link;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`link.replace` doesn't change the text in-situ, it makes a new string. Trying changing the line from `link.replace(link...` to `link = link.replace(link..`.

Answer (score 0):

`replace` *returns* a version of the string with the replacement made; the string is not replaced in-situ. So `link = link.replace...` rather than simply `link.replace`.

Comment: Wow your answer was scarily-similar to mine... I swear I didn't copy.

Comment: Well, if you try it out it does in fact accept more than one argument. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @David: Well *that's* interesting. Good to know. I was surprised to see that working from IE6 to Firefox to Opera to Chrome. But it did.

Comment: The only thing that doesn't work with multiple arguments is the alert function, but I've found an easy way around that: Just make another function and plug the arguments array into a for loop and alert the arguments[indexes] on invocation.

Comment: @David: So long as you know you're off in unspecified land and therefore it may not work reliably cross-browser going forward, even if it works on most now: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75233634 Rather than rely on that, I'd probably just do `document.write(Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ''))` if you really want to do that. That *is* specified to work.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, `replace` doesn't change the variable, it just returns a new one.  But in this case, you don't really want to replace something, you just want to concatenate some stuff around it.

IMO, you don't need the `replace` function for that:

```
function makeIntoLink(link) {
    if (link.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(.com)/)) {
        link = '<a href="http://www.' + link + '">' + link + '</a>';
    }
    return link;
}
```

(I've also removed your `\"` escapes by using different quote characters for the JS string literal and the HTML attributes. This makes it a mite less hard to read, IMHO).